# Create primary constructor for singleton object when using ModuleDef

Tags: scala, macros

When inspecting any "regularly" created module, e.g. `object Foo`, there is a non empty body which looks like this:

```
def <init>() = {
  super.<init>();
  ()
}
```

Apparently that's the special constructor used to initialise the module.

I want to synthetically create a `ModuleDef`, so how do I define a corresponding tree for that constructor for its `Template`? Is there a utility method in the macro universe / context I can use?

---

**Edit**: A "regular" object's template body looks like the following, using `showRaw`:

```
DefDef(Modifiers(), nme.CONSTRUCTOR, List(), List(List()), TypeTree(),
  Block(List(pendingSuperCall), Literal(Constant(())))))))
```

After type checking the `pendingSuperCall` becomes

```
Apply(Select(Super(This(TypeName("Foo")), tpnme.EMPTY), nme.CONSTRUCTOR), List())
```